# Typesetting braces to the index

Tags: xetex, indexing, xindy

I am trying to put `{` in index using `xindy` as my index processor and `xelatex` as the typesetting format:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\index{\texttt{\{}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

However, I get the following error:

```
Runaway argument?
{\texttt{\{}} \printindex \end{document} 
! File ended while scanning use of \@wrindex.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<*> test.tex
```

What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Nontheless, I consider this a LaTeX bug which is annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues:

- if you want to format index entry with `\texttt`, `\textbf` or similar 
  command, use index entry in the form:

  `\index{word@\textbf{word}`
- for index entries which are not alphanumeric, you should provide sort key. so if you want to sort left brace as braceleft, use this:

  `\index{braceleft@\texttt{\textbraceleft}}`

this will create following `.ind` file after running

```
 xindy -L english -C utf8 -M texindy filename.idx

\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroup{B}
  \item \texttt{\textbraceleft}, 1

\end{theindex}
```

if you don't want to sort it under some letter, use

```
\index{\relax@\texttt{\textbraceleft}}
```

this produces:

```
\begin{theindex}
  \providecommand*\lettergroupDefault[1]{}
  \providecommand*\lettergroup[1]{%
      \par\textbf{#1}\par
      \nopagebreak
  }

  \lettergroupDefault{default}
  \item \texttt{\textbraceleft}, 1

\end{theindex}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can do this as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\index{\texttt{\textbraceleft}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

But this time `xindy` gives the following error message:

```
ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string
```

or alternatively as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{document}
This is a test
\index{\texttt{\char"007B}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

but then again, `xindy` converts `\char"007B` (in the `.idx` file) to `\char007B` (in the `.ind` file) perhaps because `"` has special meaning for `xindy` and `xindy` simply ignores it.

Alternative, I can do it as

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{fontspec}
\chardef\mylb="007B
\begin{document}
This is a test
\index{\texttt{\mylb}}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

But this time `xindy` gives the following error message:

```
ERROR: CHAR: index 0 should be less than the length of the string
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the [following solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/P9eRFbJ66vk) by Heiko Oberdiek:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begingroup
  \lccode`0=`\{
  \lccode`1=`\}
\lowercase{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\BraceLeft{0}%
  \newcommand\BraceRight{1}%
}
\newcommand*{\Index}[1]{%
  \index{#1}%
}

\begin{document}
foo\Index{"\BraceLeft @\string\textbraceleft}
\printindex
\end{document}
```

I do not understand German and I just copied his TeX code. If you speak German, please edit my answer and add some details.